# How to transform a sequence of elements representing 1...n sections to a sequence of pairs/tuples?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have some LINQ code that extracts bookmarks from PDFs that match a certain naming convention (using Aspose.Pdf):

```
IOrderedEnumerable<Bookmark> magicBookmarks = (
    from    bookmark in allBookmarks.AsEnumerable()
    where   bookmark.Title.StartsWith(MAGIC_PHRASE) 
    // ...  other criteria
    orderby bookmark.PageNumber ascending
    select  bookmark
);
```

The `Bookmark` class has a property called `PageNumber` that gets the page number where a bookmark starts. In my situation, a bookmark can represent a section of 1...n pages.

What I'd like to do is transform this sequence into another sequence of `Tuple<int, int>` (or some comparable "pair" structure) where Item1 of each pair equals the `PageNumber` value of the corresponding element in the source sequence and Item2 equals the `PageNumber' value of the *next* element in the source sequence minus 1 (for the sake of this exercise, assume that all Bookmarks in the source sequence occur in succession in the document from which they were extracted).

In short, I want the end result to be a sequence of pairs that represent the start and end pages of each bookmarked PDF section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Enumerable.Zip` for this by zipping the enumeration with itself just skipping the first element:

```
var results = magicBookmarks.Zip(magicBookmarks.Skip(1), 
                                 (a, b) => new 
                                           { 
                                             PageNumber = a.PageNumber, 
                                             PageNumberNext = b.PageNumber - 1 
                                           });

foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Page: {0}, Next: {1}", item.PageNumber, item.PageNumberNext);
}
```

Comment: I like it. One question: What happens when you get to the last element of the first sequence since you'll now exceed the bounds of the second (the one you called Skip(1) on)? I'd check myself but I'm nowhere near a debugger.

Comment: the output will be N-1 pairs, there is nothing to Zip with for the last item

Comment: I can live with that. Thanks!